# Printing a binary number in LC-3 Assembly

Tags: assembly, lc3

I'm trying to print a binary number to the console using LC-3 assembly.

What I've tried so far includes (but isn't limited to):

```
        binary .fill b10000110
        lea r0, binary
        puts ; prints garbage
        ld r0, binary
        out ; prints 0 (I know it only prints one character but I don't know why it chooses to print 0)
        lea r1, binary
        and r2, r2, #0
loop    ldr r0, r1, r2
        out
        add r2, r2, #1
        and r3, r3, #0
        not r3, r2
        add r3, r3, #1
        add r3, r3, #8 ; I know all the binary numbers will be exactly 8 bits long
        brz end
        add r3, r3, #0 ; to be safe
        brnzp loop
end
        ; more code...
```

None of this works particularly well. I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out the proper way to do this, but everything I'm thinking of relies on `binary` being a string, which I can't do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LC-3, the `OUT` trap subroutine takes the value currently stored in register `R0`, finds the corresponding ASCII value and outputs it to the console, while the `PUT` trap subroutine takes the value stored in `R0` as a memory, and iterates through all the data stored at that address, outputting each byte as ASCII to the console, until it finds a  NULL character.

In the example you gave, `PUTS` will print out the ASCII representation of `b10000110`, followed by garbage until it happens to hit a NULL character whereas `OUT` will simply print the ASCII representation of `b10000110`.

Subsequently, to actually print a 0 or a 1, we must print the ASCII representation of those numbers, not the numbers themselves. So, we define two words, one for the ASCII character `0`, and the other for `1`.

```
ascii0  .fill x30
ascii1  .fill x31
```

So, for any 1-bit number, we can print it to the console with a simple if-else branch and the `OUT` subroutine.

```
binary  .fill b1
        LD  R1, binary
        AND R0, R1, #1
        BRnz else
        LD  R0, ascii1
        BRnzp done
else    LD  R0, ascii0
done    OUT
```

Now, we must extend this to n-bits. That is to say that we must break our n-bit number into a series of 1-bit numbers that we can easily print. To achieve this, all we need is a simple `AND` and a mask for the i<sup>th</sup> bit (e.g. given the 8-bit number `b10000110`, to determine the 3<sup>rd</sup> least significant bit, we would use the mask `b00000100`). So, for an 8-bit number, we will need the sequence of masks `b10000000`, `b01000000`, ..., `b00000001`. There are several ways to do this, such as starting with `b10000000` and left-shifting/multiplying by 2 for each bit, however for the sake of simplicity we will use a lookup table.

```
masks   .fill b10000000
        .fill b01000000
        .fill b00100000
        .fill b00010000
        .fill b00001000
        .fill b00000100
        .fill b00000010
        .fill b00000001
```

To choose the mask before we print out each bit, we can use a simple for-loop branch.

```
        AND R4, R4, #0   ;clears the register we will count with
        LD  R1, binary
        LEA R2, masks    ;finds the address in memory of the first mask
loop    LDR R3, R2, #0   ;load the mask from the address stored in R2
        ADD R2, R2, #1   ;next mask address
        AND R0, R1, R3
        ;print out 1-bit number
        ADD R4, R4, #1
        ADD R0, R4, #-8  ;sets condition bit zero when R4 = 8
        BRn loop         ;loops if R4 < 8
```

Finally, we have our completed program.

```
        .ORIG x3000

        AND R4, R4, #0   ;clears the register we will count with
        LD  R1, binary
        LEA R2, masks    ;finds the address in memory of the first mask
loop    LDR R3, R2, #0   ;load the mask from the address stored in R2
        ADD R2, R2, #1   ;next mask address
        AND R0, R1, R3
        BRnz else 
        LD  R0, ascii1
        BRnzp done
else    LD  R0, ascii0
done    OUT
        ADD R4, R4, #1
        ADD R0, R4, #-8  ;sets condition bit zero when R4 = 8
        BRn loop         ;loops if R4 < 8
        HALT

masks   .fill b10000000
        .fill b01000000
        .fill b00100000
        .fill b00010000
        .fill b00001000
        .fill b00000100
        .fill b00000010
        .fill b00000001
ascii0  .fill x30
ascii1  .fill x31
binary  .fill b10000110
        .END
```

Comment: Cheers - I ended up using a method very similar to that :)

Comment: It simplifies the branching if you move `'0`' into a register and conditionally add `1`.  (I guess loading `'0'` from memory makes some sense, but you could use LEA to load a small constant in position-dependent code if PC is known to be in the low 256B of address space.)